# Is there any way to use F-Bounded Polymorphism to define map as in a Functor

Tags: scala

I would like to implement a "map" method such that it returns the concrete container subtype. Something along the lines of

```
trait Result[+T, Self[A] <: Result[A, Self]] {
  def map[A](f: T => A): Self[A]
}


case class Value[T](t: T) extends Result[T, Value[T]] {
  override def map[A](f: (T) => A): Value[A] = Value(f(t))
}
```

But this doesn't compile.  Is there something missing?

Answer (score 0):

Second parameter of the "Result" type requires the higher kind type: not a "Value[T]", but simple "Value" instead.

```
trait Result[+T, Self[A] <: Result[A, Self]] {
  def map[A](f: T => A): Self[A]
}


case class Value[T](t: T) extends Result[T, Value] {
  override def map[A](f: T => A): Value[A] = Value(f(t))
}

val v = Value(1)

v.map(x ⇒ (x * 2) + "ab") // Value(2ab)
```